# AWS codeBuild with larger files

Tags: amazon-web-services, deployment, continuous-operation

I've set up a CodeBuild on AWS which works fine.
Basically I need to do 3 steps

1. `docker-compose up -d`
2. Dump my MysQL.sql into the docker container
3. Do some smaller adjustments in the docker container.

since my *.sql file is ~130mb I stored it using `git lfs` which seems not to be supported by CodeBuild.

Lets not talk about why I need this dump for building my application, it is something I cannot change currently.

How can I get my *.sql file on CodeBuild?
Using VPC MySQL is not an option since the costs does not make any sense when I just need it for the deployment.
Is there any other possibility?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Depending on where your Git repository is hosted, you may be able to download the file manually somehow, as part of a build step (or whatever it’s called on CodeBuild).

Comment: git repo is hosted on github - so manually download is not an option unfortunately

Comment: Not necessarily. Take a look [at this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34931751/1025421).

Comment: hmm : ) hacky but I'll try it ;)

Comment: hm not really what I like to have. it has other problems. 
Can't I link s3 to that directly?